# click event not working in angular 8 in mobile device

Tags: html, css, angular

A click event is not working on mobile devices. But it's working fine on other devices. If anyone knows please help to find a solution.

app.component.html:

```
    <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
        <li *ngFor="let topic of topicsList;let i=index;"(click)="getContentList(topic)" >
            <i class="fa fa-book"></i> &nbsp;{{topic.name}}
            <div *ngIf="topic.obtainMarks> 0" style="color: black">Competency level : {{topic.obtainMarks}} %
            </div>
        </li>
   </ul>
```

app.component.ts:

```
getContentList(topic: Topics): void {
  console.log(topic);
}
```

Comment: do u have `user-select: none;` in your css?

Comment: Can this be reproduced within mobile device mode within a web browser, or is it only within the physical mobile device? Also what type/version of browser is that mobile device using?

Comment: mobile browser.

Comment: Some articles suggests using type="button" on the button instead of type="submit". But I see you use a list element click handler. Not sure if that'll work. Try instead to add the click handler on a button element instead of li element. The li element is not a form element anyways and has no click event I think. Press F12 and check events

Answer (score -3):

Try using `ng-click` instead of `(click)`. I hope it will work.

```
<li *ngFor="let topic of topicsList;let i=index;" ng-click="getContentList(topic)">
```

Comment: Then can you check if any div is overlaying upon your controls?

Comment: This is an AngularJS method, not an Angular 2+ method of using click.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick AngularJs uses ng-click 
https://angular.io/guide/user-input Angular uses (click)